# Server-side C# and ActiveX C#

Tags: c#, .net, activex

What is the difference between having an ActiveX control written in C# on your website, and having a website written in C#?

Comment: The ActiveX control runs on the client, and your website code runs on your server.

Comment: I understand. So, as an example, an ActiveX control could obtain `Environment.UserName` and can be displayed in the browser for better personalization?

Comment: Thank you Michael. _sidenote: Just tested. Same can be done server-side._

Comment: Nope, that's not correct, Jason. Make sure you're not looking at the *server-side* value.

Comment: Oh, stupid me. I forgot about that. Thanks for pointing that out Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A website written in C# - This will be hosted on IIS, and generate a HTML response to be send to the client browser. This runs at the server end.

ActiveX control - ActiveX controls, mini program building blocks, can serve to create distributed applications working over the Internet through web browsers, something similar to Java Applets. This executes at the client end

Answer (score 2):

Server-side C# produces HTML that can be requested and displayed by virtualy every browser on every OS.

ActiveX controls are proprietary client-side applications that run only in a very specific client configuration, i.e. Internet Explorer on a limited set of OS.